# Wordpress - How to create custom post type without creating page

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a *custom post type* to manage some things on wordpress. But i don't want that the post create a single page to each and single one. 
How can i disable this function of wordpress?

Comment: Would you care to share any code of what you have tried? Also have you looked at the codex itself: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type - the publicly_queryable option may be what you are after?

Comment: I'm using the WCK plugin. Every custom post type record that I create, creates a page and I dont want that

Comment: A friendly little tip for future SO posts - include this information in your original question as we are not mind readers. If it is a custom plugin then you will need to speak to the developers, have you posted a support request or read through their forum pages? https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator

Comment: You can also use this [**Wordpress Custom Post generator**](https://generatewp.com/post-type/) may be a better solution for you…

Answer (score 1):

While creating the custom post type, You can disable the permalink section. Please check on this thread,

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108652/remove-custom-post-type-permalink